# MySQL using current results for subquery. Correlated subquery?

Tags: mysql, correlated-subquery

I have a table that contains the following fields
system_id
partner_id
uptime

I'm trying to get output that shows:
system_id, uptime, partner_id, partner_uptime

So for every row that comes back from an initial select all I need to check if the partner id is in the table and retrieve it's uptime value. It's simple enough to do in excel but with 2M+ records it could take a while!

Can someone please help construct a basic query for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple `self join` query here, assuming `partner_id` references to `system_id`:

```
select t.system_id, t.uptime, t1.partner_id, t1.uptime as partner_uptime
from table t join table t1 on t.system_id = t2.partner_id
where //your condition
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! There was a typo where it should read: "t1.partner_id" not t2 but it fixed my problem. Much simpler than I thought too.